# How do I output a single pixel on the monitor using assembly language?

Tags: graphics

I want a low-level understanding of how a pixel is displayed on a monitor.

I am guessing that the point at which I want to display a pixel must be modified in the frame buffer, which should be sent as a signal to the monitor. But, on low level, how do I find out what part of memory represents the frame buffer? I also guess that the monitor contains circuitry that decodes a signal and displays pixels on the monitor.

So, I basically want to know what happens underneath a Graphics API call like setpixel(x, y).

Comment: Are you asking about concepts or about code?  If it's about concepts, what research have you done?  If you're asking for a low-level explanation of everything that happens, from setting memory to the video card's handling to the monitor's circuitry, that sounds pretty broad, and you'd probably be better focusing on a specific aspect of it that you don't understand.  I find it hard to determine from this what you want to know and to extract a single answerable question.

Comment: The question seems to ask about the mechanism of cpu->screen output, and as such is on-topic (computer architecture). However, as currently stated it may be too broad to answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the screen, and other devices in the chain (for instance, is the screen connected by VGA cable, or HDMI, or directly to the memory via a DMA access, etc.), so your question is too broad to answer per se.

Just to give a superficial answer, when someone builds a computer, a common practice is to reserve a segment in the memory that "reflects" the screen (i.e., each cell in this memory represents a pixel). The exact location of this segment may vary. Then, according to the way the screen is connected to the "computer", one needs to repeatedly "read" that segment and load its content to the "screen".

For instance, the graphic card may read this content, convert it into a [VGA signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Graphics_Array#Signal_timings) and output it on the VGA output  (which is then "read" by the screen, which presents the pixels according to the content).